# how to pass a float/int/decimal from view to contoller using FormCollection in Asp.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can retrieve a string but I can't retrieve a decimal/int/float.

When retrieving the the string I used this.

```
 customer.FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"];
 customer.LastName = formCollection["LastName"];
```

Or

```
 FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"],
 LastName = formCollection["LastName"]
```

Then I tried it to a decimal/foat/integer, but having an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' "

```
Amount= formCollection["Amount"]
```

so I try this

```
Amount= int32.Parse.formCollection["Amount"]
Amount= int32.TryParse.formCollection["Amount"]
```

but it's overloading.
Can someone know how to collect a int/float/decimal from view to controller??

Comment: Overloading? How about using `int.Parse(formCollection["Amount"])`? Also depends on how you are sending data around. Clearly not in a typed way, which would be easier

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formCollection["Amount"]` is a string, because you use an `<input type="text" />` I guess. `int32.Parse(string s)` wants a string. So just write:

```
Amount = Int32.Parse(formCollection["Amount"]);
```

Comment: Taysumi Thank you for your response